# Access props.location object from redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux, redux-saga

My end goal is to access `this.props.location.pathname` inside redux-saga when making API calls. Here's my current working solution, albeit with react raising an error. I'm using `mxstbr/react-boilerplate-brand` as my codebase.

In my wrapping component, `App`, I have the following line in my render method.

```
render() {
  this.props.onUpdateLocation(this.props.location)
}
```

In my `mapDispatchToProps` I have following. Basically I'm just saving `this.props.location` into the React store:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onUpdateLocation: (location) => {
      dispatch(updateLocation(location));
    },
    dispatch,
  };
}
```

Inside my `redux-saga` I access the location from state and just use it as need be; however, here's the error React raises.

```
warning.js:44 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

I can't put it in `componentWillMount` because that only gets fired once when the app starts, and I can't put it in `componentWillUpdate` because `this.props.location` gets updated in the `render` method. I can't put it in `componentDidUpdate` because that's too late.

Am I just missing some easy obvious way to access the react-router location inside my redux-saga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have `<Route path='profile' component={ Profile } />`
the Profile component can access the react-router props in the second argument `ownProps` of:

`mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps])` and
`mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps])`

Comment: Finally got around to attacking this issue and while I can access the route info from `ownProps`, the result is the matching expression, rather than the real route. I.e. `/brand/*/details` instead of `/brand/starbucks/details`.

Comment: give the wildcard a name `/brand/:name/details`

Comment: You're awesome! I'll post my eventual solution of accessing these params from within redux-saga.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.onUpdateLocation(this.props.location.pathname);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.props.onUpdateLocation(nextProps.location.pathname);
  }
  render() {
    // Render stuff here
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onUpdateLocation: (location) => {
      dispatch(updateLocation(location));
    },
    dispatch,
  };
}
```

My reducer receives the action and updates `location` in the state. Now I can access the current pathname using a selector that grabs `location` from the state.

## Long Answer:

IGL's answer is pretty good info, especially the wildcard naming info that you can use in routes and is returned by the `ownProps` param of `mapDispatchToProps`. Here is how I solved the problem...

Initially I thought the warning was about be accessing `this.props.location` or something else; however, it was a much simpler issue. React doesn't like it when you call a function without it being because of an action like a click. The warning message, which suggest a solution, led me on the right track.

First to see what fired when and where, I placed each of the React lifecycle functions in my code, console logging when they were hit. `componentWillMount, componentDidMount, componentWillReceiveProps, shouldComponentUpdate, componentWillUpdate, componentDidUpdate, componentWillUnmount`.

I discovered that `componentWillMount` is fired on initial page load, and `componentWillReceiveProps` is fired on each navigation. With that in mind, I console logged `this.props.location` and discovered that `componentWillReceiveProps` still had the old location; however, it's takes one param, `nextProps` that has the new location. so, `nextProps.location` is what I want. I placed this in my App container, which takes other containers as its children, and now I can access the current location in my sagas where I use it to make API calls.